# Median code explanation

Tags: python, median

My professor wrote this median function and I don't understand it very well. Can someone please explain the part about `i = len(list)/2` and `median = avg()` and the `else` statement?

```
def avg_list(numbers):  
    sum = 0 
    for num in numbers:
        sum += num

    avg = float(sum)/len(numbers)
    print avg

def median(list):            
    list.sort()
    if len(list)%2 == 0:
        #have to take avg of middle two
        i = len(list)/2
        median = avg()
    else:
        #find the middle (remembering that lists start at 0)
        i = len(list)/2
        median = list        
    return median
```

To add from an example I saw, for even list length:

```
def median(s):
    i = len(s)
    if not i%2:
        return (s[(i/2)-1]+s[i/2])/2.0
    return s[i/2]
```

This works very well but I don't understand the last `return s[i/2]`?

For odd list length:

```
x = [1,2,5,2,3,763,234,23,1,234,21,3,2134,23,54]
median = sorted(x)[len(x)/2]
```

Since `x` has a list length of odd, wouldn't the `[len(x)/2]` be a floating number index? I'm not getting this all the way? Any explanation better than mine is much appreciated.

Comment: this code seems incorrect to me.

Comment: please flag homework as such. thank you.

Comment: @samack: It's not clear it *is* homework. Understanding what your professor has written isn't the same as being asked to explain it in an assignment... I don't see anything wrong with this question.

Comment: `len(x)/2` returns an integer, since both `len(x)` and `2` are ints.

Comment: @eryksun my apologies for not use '//' operator, only been doing this for 3 weeks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We're missing some code here, but we can puzzle it out.

The comments here are instructive.  When we check:

```
    if len(list)%2 == 0:
```

Then we're checking to see if the list is of even length.  If a list has an even number of members, then there is no true "middle" element, and so:

```
    #have to take avg of middle two
        i = len(list)/2
        median = avg()
```

We assume that the avg() function is going to return the average of the two middle elements.  Since you didn't include a definition of an avg function, it's possible that this is really supposed to be an avg_list function taking the middle two elements of the list.

Now, if the list is of odd length, there is a middle element, and so:

```
    else:
        #find the middle (remembering that lists start at 0)
        i = len(list)/2
        median = list
```

Now this looks kinda wrong to me too, but my guess is that the intention is that this should read:

```
median = list[i]
```

That would be us returning the middle element of the list.  Since the list has been sorted, that middle element is the true median of the list.

Hope this helps!

Comment: When you say, that we assume the avg() function will return the average of the two middle elements. Where do you see that? How does any part of this program suggest that it's picking the middle two numbers and dividing? Thanks for your explanation on the rest... it helped very much!

Comment: GG: To be clear, when I say "we assume," that's literal: I'm assuming it, because a standard definition of the median of an even number of elements is the mean of the middle two elements.  But as was pointed out in a previous comment, avg() is not a function defined here, and thus this isn't legal code.

Comment: I'm sure he meant it as avg_list() I think.

Answer (score 12):

Why this is is very wrong, line by line:

```
def median(list):              # 1

    list.sort()                # 2

        if len(list)%2 == 0:   
        #have to take avg of middle two
            i = len(list)/2    # 3
            median = avg()     # 4
        else:
            #find the middle (remembering that lists start at 0)
            i = len(list)/2    # 5
            median = list      # 6

        return median
```

`#1`: It's a bad idea to give your variables the same name as data types, namely `list`.

`#2`: `list.sort()` will modify the list that is being passed. One would expect a getter like `median()` not to do that.

`#4` It calls a function `avg()` with no arguments, which is completely meaningless, even if such a function was defined.

`#3` and `#5` are calculated the same way regardless of the `if` branch taken. Regardless, `i` is never used.

`#6` It sets `median` to the original `list`, which makes zero sense.

---

Here's how I would rewrite this (while maintaining clarity):

```
def median(alist):

    srtd = sorted(alist) # returns a sorted copy
    mid = len(alist)/2   # remember that integer division truncates

    if len(alist) % 2 == 0:  # take the avg of middle two
        return (srtd[mid-1] + srtd[mid]) / 2.0
    else:
        return srtd[mid]
```

Also, the `avg_list()` function (which is not used nor could be used in `median()`) could be rewritten as:

```
def avg_list(numbers):  
    return float(sum(numbers))/len(numbers)
```

[`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) is a function that returns the sum of all elements in an iterable.

Comment: helluva thanks to you! Thanks for the awesome explanation and education :)

Comment: NullUserException ఠ_ఠ i tried your code looked perfect but i get an error when entering 3 and 6 TypeError: list indices must be integers, not float

Comment: If you are using python 3 (or `from __future__ import division`), then `len(alist)/2` is a floating point division; Use integer division `len(alist)//2` instead

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure it's *trying* to say, "If the list is of odd size, just take the central element; otherwise take the mean of the central *two* elements" - but I can't see that that's what the code is *actually* doing at all.

In particular:

- It's calling an `avg()` function (not `avg_list`, note) but without any arguments
- It's ignoring the value of `i` after computing it in the same way in both branches

Are you sure that's the complete code which is *meant* to work?

Comment: To all... verbatim, I copied and pasted what my professor wrote for us to go off of and I couldn't understand since he left out all that you guys mentioned. This is homework, yes. I'm not asking for answers, just explanation. I just gave my professor the benefit of the doubt, he knew what he was doing. Guess not...

Answer (score 2):

You can also decide to always return the average of the middle sub-array of the ordered list:
For instance return the average of [4,5] out of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], and that of [5] out of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

A python implementation would be:

```
def median(a):
    ordered = sorted(a)
    length = len(a)
    return float((ordered[length/2] + ordered[-(length+1)/2]))/2
```