# How to find Median

Tags: python, median

I have data like this.

```
Ram,500
Sam,400
Test,100
Ram,800
Sam,700
Test,300
Ram,900
Sam,800
Test,400
```

What is the shortest way to fine the "median" from above data.
My result should be something like...

Median = 1/2(n+1), where n is the number of data values in the sample.

```
Test 500
Sam 700
Ram 800
```

Comment: If you're just looking for median algorithms try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578689/median-code-explanation)

Answer (score 40):

Python 3.4 includes [statistics](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html) built-in, so you can use the method [`statistics.median`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.median):

```
>>> from statistics import median
>>> median([1, 3, 5])
 3
```

Answer (score 35):

Use [numpy's median](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.median.html) function.

Answer (score 31):

Its a little unclear how your data is actually represented, so I've assumed it is a list of tuples:

```
data = [('Ram',500), ('Sam',400), ('Test',100), ('Ram',800), ('Sam',700), 
        ('Test',300), ('Ram',900), ('Sam',800), ('Test',400)]

from collections import defaultdict

def median(mylist):
    sorts = sorted(mylist)
    length = len(sorts)
    if not length % 2:
        return (sorts[length / 2] + sorts[length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0
    return sorts[length / 2]

data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for el in data:
    data_dict[el[0]].append(el[1])

print [(key,median(val)) for key, val in data_dict.items()] 
print median([5,2,4,3,1])   
print median([5,2,4,3,1,6])
#output:
[('Test', 300), ('Ram', 800), ('Sam', 700)]
3
3.5
```

The function `median` returns the median from a list. If there are an even number of entries it takes the middle value of the middle two entries (this is standard).

I've used [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dict keyed by your data and their values, which is a more useful representation of your data.

Comment: Maybe the function would be a little clearer if you factor out `n = len(sorts)`

Comment: median() crashes on empty lists, you might want to add `if not mylist: return 0` at the beginning.

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain it doesn't crash but it raises an exception, which you can catch. this is correct behaviour, as the median of an empty list is *undefined* and definitely not "0" (which is the median of something like `[2,-1,0]`)

Comment: I guess it depends on how you look at it. Anyway having to catching an "IndexError" for an undefined value does not seem very idiomatic to me. Maybe raising a ValueError, or returning a None...

Answer (score 4):

Check this out:

```
def median(lst):
    even = (0 if len(lst) % 2 else 1) + 1
    half = (len(lst) - 1) / 2
    return sum(sorted(lst)[half:half + even]) / float(even)
```

Note:

`sorted(lst)` produces a sorted copy of `lst`;

`sum([1]) == 1`;

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get the median of a list with integer data:

```
x = [1,3,2]
print "The median of x is:",sorted(x)[len(x)//2]
```

Comment: For anyone about to look it up: // means truncating division (just like normal division in python 2.x)

Comment: This is of course in correct, as it does not work for even number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

I started with user3100512's answer and quickly realized it doesn't work for an even number of items.  I added some conditionals to it to compute the median.

```
def median(x):
    if len(x)%2 != 0:
        return sorted(x)[len(x)/2]
    else:
        midavg = (sorted(x)[len(x)/2] + sorted(x)[len(x)/2-1])/2.0
        return midavg

    median([4,5,6,7])
```

should return 5.5