# Python: Iterating through multiple lists to get median of each item of same index

Tags: python, list

Let's say for example one wants to iterate through 3 list containing the same number of items. How would I be able to compare the items of same index and put the median of those in a new list called median list?

```
example output:

list_1 = [1,2,3]
list_2 = [1,3,5]
list_3 = [2,4,6]

median_list = [1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: you need to do something by yourself. This is not a place to crowdsource your problems for free.

Comment: I'm new to coding and have been attempting to try since yesterday. If you can't help, thanks anyway.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python for ways of finding the median in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) and [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> list_1 = [1,2,3]
>>> list_2 = [1,3,5]
>>> list_3 = [2,4,6]

>>> zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)  # To make 1st items pair, 2nd items pairs, ...
[(1, 1, 2), (2, 3, 4), (3, 5, 6)]

>>> [sorted(xs)[1] for xs in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]
[1, 3, 5]
```

If you are using Python 3.4+, you can use [`statistics.median`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.median):

```
>>> [statistics.median(xs) for xs in zip(list_1, list_2, list_3)]
[1, 3, 5]
```