# Error when looking for median in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the median in a given list but keep getting the wrong answer. What am I missing in my code below?

```
def median(x):
x = sorted(x)
final = 0
position = (len(x) + 1)/2
if (len(x) + 1) % 2 == 0:
    final = x[position - 1]
else:
    final = (x[position - 1] + x[position])/2
return final
```

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? You need integer division, but might not be using it.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101534/5660284

Comment: your function does not have proper indentation. Python has mandatory indentation. everything beneat the def keyword that is part of the function should be indented. Moreover you should be using // for integer division if this is python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should produce the correct result in Python 3 by employing integer division.

```
def median(x):
  x = sorted(x) #sort list
  final = 0 #confusing var name. try res
  position = (len(x) + 1)//2 #integer division forces the index to be an int
  if (len(x) + 1) % 2 == 0: #should use len(x) % 2 == 1 for efficiency
    final = x[position - 1] #set result to median of array
  else:
    final = (x[position - 1] + x[position])/2 #set result to median of array
  return final

print(median([1,3,2,5]))
```

In python 2 you could use floating point division instead of integer division and you would get the same result (though just use integer to be safe) Except the division in the `else` block should be over a float to force it to return a float.

As in:

```
  if (len(x) + 1) % 2 == 0: #should use len(x) % 2 == 1 for efficiency
    final = x[position - 1] #set result to median of array
  else:
    final = (x[position - 1] + x[position])/2.0 #set result to median of array
  return final
```

If you want the program to be dually compatible with both versions you must employ both of these changes

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not using integer division and thus are vetting invalid answers at points in your program. The line beginning with position needs to become:

```
position = (len(x) + 1)//2
```

The double division sign will make it integer division and you will no longer get errors when trying to put floats as array values.