# REVISED WITH COMMENTS v1: Multiprocessing on same dict/list

Tags: python, dictionary, queue, python-2.x, python-multiprocessing

I am fairly new to python, kindly excuse me for insufficient information if any. As a part of the curriculum , I got introduced to python for quants/finance, I am studying multiprocessing and trying to understand this better. I tried modifying the problem given and now I am stuck mentally with the problem.

**Problem:**

I have a function which gives me ticks, in ohlc format.

```
{'scrip_name':'ABC','timestamp':1504836192,'open':301.05,'high':303.80,'low':299.00,'close':301.10,'volume':100000}
```

every minute. I wish to do the following calculation concurrently and preferably append/insert in the samelist

- Find the Moving Average of the last 5 close data
- Find the Median of the last 5 open data
- Save the tick data to a database.

so expected data is likely to be

```
['scrip_name':'ABC','timestamp':1504836192,'open':301.05,'high':303.80,'low':299.00,'close':301.10,'volume':100000,'MA_5_open':300.25,'Median_5_close':300.50]
```

Assuming that the data is going to a db, its fairly easy to write a simple dbinsert routine to the database, I don't see that as a great challenge, I can spawn a to execute a insert statement for every minute.

How do I sync 3 different functions/process( a function to insert into db, a function to calculate the average, a function to calculate the median), while holding in memory 5 ticks to calculate the 5 period, simple average Moving Average and push them back to the dict/list.

The following assumption, challenges me in writing the multiprocessing routine. can someone guide me.  I don't want to use pandas dataframe.

**====REVISION/UPDATE===**

The reason, why I don't want any solution on pandas/numpy is that, my objective is to understand the basics, and not the nuances of a new library. Please don't mistake my need for understanding to be arrogance or not wanting to be open to suggestions.

The advantage of having

```
p1=Process(target=Median,arg(sourcelist))
p2=Process(target=Average,arg(sourcelist))
p3=process(target=insertdb,arg(updatedlist))
```

would help me understand the possibility of scaling processes based on no of functions /algo components.. But how should I make sure p1&p2 are in sync while p3 should execute post p1&p2

Comment: hello also for future questions, i've found this helpful : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: To share a dictionary, list, array, etc, you need to use a [`multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager) (which is a subclass of [`multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager)) and the proxies for those types it supports. That said, performance is usually better using `multiprocessing.Queue` (which doesn't need a `Manager`).

Comment: Martineau, you are right regarding the queue, its likely to be faster, but sometimes it may not serve in all efficiency.lets assume i have a queue_db , so i have a function:dbinsert to read and update db, it will be ok.

what would happen, if in the future i intend to distribute the workload of different algo results on the samelist as thats the instant of data for that minute. so i have 60 seconds to solve possibly 20 algos and update it back to the same list, before proceeding to the next update

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to use multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
def db_func(ma, med):
    db.save(something)

def backtest_strat(d, db_func):
    a = d.get('avg')
    s = map(sum, a)
    db_func(s/len(a), median(a))

with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
    from functools import partial
    bs = partial(backtest_strat, db_func=db_func)
    print(p.map(bs, [{'avg': [1,2,3,4,5], 'median': [1,2,3,4,5]}]))
```

also see :

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101655/2026508

note that this will not speed up anything unless there are a lot of slices.

so for the speed up part:

```
def get_slices(data)
    for slice in data:
        yield {'avg': [1,2,3,4,5], 'median': [1,2,3,4,5]}

p.map(bs, get_slices)
```

from what i understand multiprocessing works by message passing via pickles, so the `pool.map` when called should have access to all three things, the two arrays, and the db_save function. There are of course other ways to go about it, but hopefully this shows one way to go about it.

Comment: Thanx for a quick response, but this will not help. ooops am new here, so having trouble responding , kindly bear with me

Comment: The example of Median or Average is an example, it could be a much complicated function... so basically a pool of process wouldn't be ideal, as the ability of some functions will be faster than the rest.

Comment: kindly advice, what if functions are separate for median and average , how should I synchronize and maintain integrity

Comment: Hi jmunsch, Sorry was away on personal time, I will try to run your code and try understanding how it works. I have just started to read about partials, will keep you posted on my improved level of understanding :) at the end of this exercise. Thanx.

Answer (score -1):

> **Question**: how should I make sure p1&p2 are in sync while p3 should execute post p1&p2

If you *sync* all Processes, computing **one** Task (p1,p2,p3) couldn't be faster as the slowes Process are be.
In the meantime the other Processes running idle.

It's called ["Producer - Consumer Problem"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#condition-objects).
Solution using `Queue` all Data serialize, no **synchronize** required.

```
# Process-1
def Producer()
    task_queue.put(data)

# Process-2
def Consumer(task_queue)
    data = task_queue.get()
    # process data
```

---

You want **multiple** Consumer Processes and **one** Consumer Process gather all Results.
You don't want to use `Queue`, but `Sync Primitives`.
This Example let **all** Processes run independent.
Only the Process `Result` waits until notified.

This Example uses a **unlimited** Task Buffer `tasks = mp.Manager().list()`.
The Size could be minimized if List Entrys for **done** Tasks are reused.
If you have some very fast *algos* combine some to **one** `Process`.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

# Base class for all WORKERS
class Worker(mp.Process):
    tasks = mp.Manager().list()
    task_ready = mp.Condition()
    parties = mp.Manager().Value(int, 0)

    @classmethod
    def join(self):
        # Wait until all Data processed

    def get_task(self):
        for i, task in enumerate(Worker.tasks):
            if task is None: continue
            if not self.__class__.__name__ in task['result']:
                return (i, task['range'])
        return (None, None)

    # Main Process Loop
    def run(self):
        while True:
            # Get a Task for this WORKER
            idx, _range = self.get_task()
            if idx is None:
                break
            # Compute with self Method this _range
            result = self.compute(_range)

            # Update Worker.tasks
            with Worker.lock:
                task = Worker.tasks[idx]
                task['result'][name] = result
                parties = len(task['result'])
                Worker.tasks[idx] = task

            # If Last, notify Process Result
            if parties == Worker.parties.value:
                with Worker.task_ready:
                    Worker.task_ready.notify()

class Result(Worker):
    # Main Process Loop
    def run(self):
        while True:
            with Worker.task_ready:
                Worker.task_ready.wait()

            # Get (idx, _range) from tasks List
            idx, _range = self.get_task()
            if idx is None:
                break

            # process Task Results

            # Mark this tasks List Entry as done for reuse
            Worker.tasks[idx] = None

class Average(Worker):
    def compute(self, _range):
        return average of DATA[_range]

class Median(Worker):
    def compute(self, _range):
        return median of DATA[_range]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    DATA = mp.Manager().list()
    WORKERS = [Result(), Average(), Median()]
    Worker.start(WORKERS)

    # Example creates a Task every 5 Records
    for i in range(1, 16):
        DATA.append({'id': i, 'open': 300 + randrange(0, 5), 'close': 300 + randrange(-5, 5)})
        if i % 5 == 0:
            Worker.tasks.append({'range':(i-5, i), 'result': {}})

    Worker.join()
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***