# How to find the mean and median from alist that we put on?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

This is the code that I have.

```
#Ask for how many students will be putting for grades.
students= input ('How many students that you have: ')
print (students)

#Create a list of the students and ask for the grades.
grades = []

students_grades =[]
while students_grades != 'stop':

    students_grades = input("Enter the students grades you have, or enter 'stop' when you done: ")


    if students_grades != 'stop':
        grades.append(students_grades)
print(grades)
```

Could I ask you that how do we find the mean and median for the list that I got from this? please help me! Thank you !

Comment: Happy Coding. SO 
is about fixing _your_ Code - not implementing your homework. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you a specific questions, provide 
your code as [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, copy and paste
the error message verbatim ( word for word) into your question. Thank you.

Comment: Searching this forum for existing questions is a good way to get stuff done, read about mean in lists here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a homework question and you should just google "how to" but given that you have created a new question, I am going to provide a simple answer.

Use `numpy`.

You have a `list` called `grades`.

Do this:

```
import numpy as np

grades = np.array(grades)

print(np.mean(grades))
print(np.median(grades))
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Thank you for your help but this is the problem that I have

Comment: You need to open the terminal and install `numpy` using: `pip install numpy`