# How to sort a column and find it's median?

Tags: python, median

I have a csv file and I want to sort (lowest from greatest) the first column.
The first column's name is "CRIM".

I can read the first column, but I can't sort it, the numbers are floats.

Also, I would like to find the median of the list.

This is what I did so far:

```
import csv

with open('data.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for line in data:
      print(line['CRIM'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using `pandas` >> `dataframe.median()`

Eg data:

```
A   B   C   D
0   12  5   20  14
1   4   2   16  3
2   5   54  7   17
3   44  3   3   2
4   1   2   8   6
```

```
# importing pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 

# for your csv
# df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
  
# Creating the dataframe (example)
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[12, 4, 5, 44, 1], 
                   "B":[5, 2, 54, 3, 2], 
                   "C":[20, 16, 7, 3, 8],  
                   "D":[14, 3, 17, 2, 6]}) 
  
# Find median Even if we do not specify axis = 0, the method  
# will return the median over the index axis by default 
df.median(axis = 0)
```

```
A    5.0
B    3.0
C    8.0
D    6.0
dtype: float64
```

```
df['A'].median(axis = 0)
```

```
5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but how am i suppose to create a dataframe for this : https://www.kaggle.com/arslanali4343/real-estate-dataset?select=data.csv

I'm extracting the first colomn (CRIM).

Comment: well data frames are faster, have more features, easy to use, easy to view and on Kaggle pandas is pre-installed and everyone uses it

Answer (score 0):

https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/sorted

Use sorted():

```
CRIM_sorted = sorted(line['CRIM'])
```

For the median, you can use a package or just build your own:
[Finding median of list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python)

Comment: for some reason, when i use sorted(), It split the number from this -> 0.004, to this [".". "0". "0". "4"].