# How to get the mean and median of derived value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame of houses in different towns:

```
data = [
  ['Oxford', 2016, True],
  ['Oxford', 2016, True],
  ['Oxford', 2018, False],
  ['Cambridge', 2016, False],
  ['Cambridge', 2016, True],
  ['Brighton', 2019, True],
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['town', 'year_built', 'is_detached'])
```

I want to get the mean and median number of houses per town.

How can I do this?

I know how to get the mean (hackily):

```
len(df) / len(df.town.value_counts())
```

But I don't know how to get the median.

Comment: [Duplicate Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101524/finding-median-of-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the number of houses per town, and then [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.agg.html) with `'mean'` and `'median'`:

```
df['town'].value_counts().agg(['mean', 'median'])
```

Output:

```
mean      2.0
median    2.0
Name: town, dtype: float64
```