# list.remove(x): x not in list, when trying to find median

Tags: python, list, median

Could anyone tell me why this isn't working? I got error saying:
`ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list`.

But if I try `print max`; it prints 9,
and also if I `print min`; it prints 1.

```
list = [3,1,4,9,5,7]
max = list[0]
min = list[0]

list = list[:]
while len(list)> 2:
        for i in list:
                if(i > max):
                        max = i
                elif(i < min):
                        min = i
        list.remove(min)
        list.remove(max)

print list
```

I need to remove max and min element from list, until there are only 2 elements in order to get the median of the list.

Comment: you are using the same name for list = list[:] and the copy of the list.

Comment: This is the obligatory comment telling you not to name a `list` "list".

Comment: there's a better way to get the median, see steveha's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only initialize the min and max variables once, outside the `while` loop.

Your code will work if you initialize inside the loop.

This code works.  Note that I changed the variable names to not be Python built-ins.  You shouldn't use names that "shadow" built-ins; for example, `list` is a built-in type, so you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name.

```
lst = [3,1,4,9,5,7]

lst = lst[:]
while len(lst)> 2:
        max_val = lst[0]
        min_val = lst[0]
        for i in lst:
                if(i > max_val):
                        max_val = i
                elif(i < min_val):
                        min_val = i
        lst.remove(min_val)
        lst.remove(max_val)
        print lst
```

Note that your code is tremendously inefficient and slow.  You could speed it up a bit by using the built-in functions `max()` and `min()` but the algorithm is still inefficient.

The best thing is to just sort the list, and then pick the single value from the middle of the list (for an odd-length list) or average the middle two values (for an even-length list).  Or simply use one of the built-in functions that Python provides.

[How to find Median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482339/how-to-find-median)

Answer (score 0):

After `list.remove(min); list.remove(max)` is first run, your program goes through the `while` loop again, but `min` and `max` will keep the same values they had on the first pass through the loop, and as nothing remaining in `list` is greater than `max` or less than `min`, the variables won't be changed, and so Python will end up trying to run `list.remove(min); list.remove(max)` with the same values for `min` and `max` that were used before.  Since those values were already removed from `list`, you get an error.

The simplest solution is to set `min` and `max` at the start of the `while` loop rather than before it:

```
list = [3,1,4,9,5,7]

list = list[:]
while len(list)> 2:
        max = list[0]
        min = list[0]
        for i in list:
                if(i > max):
                        max = i
                elif(i < min):
                        min = i
        list.remove(min)
        list.remove(max) 
print list
```

Also note that [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list), [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), and [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) are already the names of builtin Python functions, and using those names for regular variables is widely considered bad practice.  You should rename them to something else (say, `lst`, `minimum`, and `maximum`).