# Python | The median is the middle number in a sorted sequence of numbers

Tags: python

```
def median (lst):
    lst.sort()
    if len(lst) % 2==0:
        print  sum(lst[len(lst)-1:len(lst)])
    else:
        print sum(len(lst)/2)

median([4, 5, 5, 4,2,5,6,9,10])
```

The error occurs at: `print sum(len(lst)/2)`

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

why doesn't it work?

Comment: You can improve this question by introducing the problem and your current method of addressing it before posting any code.

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `print sum(len(lst)/2)` with:

```
print lst[len(lst) / 2]
```

because what you want is to take the middle element of the list. What was wrong was to `sum` not on a list of numbers but on a number. What you could do if you wanted to use the sum notation is the following:

```
print sum([lst[len(lst)//2]])
```

meaning to include the number in a list.

Comment: i meant print sum(lst[len(lst)//2] . meaning i want the value in the middle index of the list. for example if i have list length of 13 i wnat the the value of index 6

Comment: @OmerMichleviz: Why do you want to sum a single number?

Comment: def median (lst):
    lst.sort()
    while lst > 0:
        if len(lst) % 2==0:
            return  sum(lst[len(lst)-1:len(lst)])
        else:
            return lst[len(lst) / 2.0]
    else:
        return 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built-in function?

```
>>> from statistics import median
>>> median([1, 3, 5])
```

above taken from this post:   [Median code explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7578689/median-code-explanation)

or, if you must do it the hard way:

```
def median(a):
ordered = sorted(a)
length = len(a)
return float((ordered[length/2] + ordered[-(length+1)/2]))/2
```

Also taken from the same post...